# Are explicitly typed regexes allowed as keys in Perl YAML dump?

Tags: regex, perl, yaml, dump

This relates to a previous question: [How can I read Perl data structures from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389945/how-can-i-read-perl-data-structures-from-python). It could be a bug in the version of the YAML parser that I'm working with (0.66), but when I run:

```
perl -MYAML -le 'do shift; print YAML::Dump( $CPAN::Config )' simple.pl
```

On the following `simple.pl`:

```
%config = (
    'color' => 'red',
    'numbers' => [5, 8],
    qr/^spam/ => qr/eggs$/,
);
```

I get:

```
---
(?-xism:^spam): !!perl/regexp (?-xism:eggs$)
color: red
numbers:
  - 5
  - 8
```

Note that the key regex doesn't have the explicit type. What gives? (Thanks!)

Comment: Alternatively, YAML::Any uses the best available YAML module on your system (either YAML::XS, YAML::Syck, YAML::Old, YAML or YAML::Tiny, in that order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man perldata`:

> *Hashes are unordered collections of scalar values indexed by their associated **string key**.*

The keys don't have a type in the YAML dump because they don't have a type in Perl. They are just strings. In you case the string `(?-xism:^spam)`

Try this:
`perl -l -e'%config = ( qr/^spam/ => qr/eggs$/); print $config{"(?-xism:^spam)"}'`

Comment: Excellent reason! :-) I figured they were just immutable objects - my brain gets stuck in Python land sometimes.